# How can I implement Track Changes functionality with InfoPath 2007/2010 in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, infopath, form, version-history

I need to track changes from version to version in my InfoPath forms that are hosted in a SharePoint 2007 form library.  Can someone walk me through what my options are?  I need to understand all of my options (XML, custom code) and the high level or detailed level steps in order to implement.

Comment: From my understanding, it seems that you wish to keep track of each modification to your forms in the SharePoint 2007 form library - if my understanding is correct, you can enable the `Versioning Settings` inside the library setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through custom code.

- First enable the Versioning for Form library. So the versions are captured in document library itself.
- Generally the infopath documents are stored as xml document in form library. So first read the current document as one xml document and the versioned(like 1,2 version etc..) document as another xml document.
- So now you have got two xml document. Just compare the nodes of each document then you can able to find the difference.
  You can use stringbuilder  to cumulate the changes.

Hope it helps. :)... Recently I had done this for my project.. It's worked..